# How to get azure function app Credentials?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-functions, azure-deployment

Every Azure Function has a publish profile containing a username and a password. I need them because I want to create a FunctionApp with Powershell and push a function with zip Deployment immediately.

The Question is:

**How can I get these two parameters from a Function, using PowerShell?**

Comment: Did my solution work? If so you could accept and up-vote it for others to refer. Or if you have further questions, just let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the code below, it works on my side.

```
$credentials = Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceGroupName YourResourceGroup -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName YourWebApp/publishingcredentials -Action list -ApiVersion 2015-08-01 -Force
$username = $credentials.Properties.PublishingUserName
$password = $credentials.Properties.PublishingPassword
```